# How to retrieve json which are inside []

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I have some JSON which is like this

```js
const data = '{"cant": ["give": "everything", "cause": "its private"] }'
```

Now how do I retrieve that? If I didn't have the 'cant': [] it would be data.give but I have the 'cant': []. So how do I get that

Comment: That's not JSON yet, it's a string. You'll need to convert to an object first.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I have it right in my code, I had to write it quickly here. But I have it correct in my code, so how would i do it?

Comment: then just use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), you should add the string/code/structure that you actually have :/

Comment: If it is already a json object you access with dots: data.cant.give, it not then convert just like @LawrenceCherone said.

Answer (score 2):

That is not json, you use {} for associative and [] for non-associative

A valid json with that data is:

```
{"cant": {"give": "everything", "cause": "its private"} }
```

Answer (score 1):

The mark-up for you JSON is in-correct.

It would depend on your use case.

It could be written like this

```
const data = {"cant": [{"give": "everything"}, {"cause": "its private"}] }
console.log (data.cant[0].give) // --> everything
```

or

```
const data = {"cant": {"give": "everything", "cause": "its private"} }
console.log (data.cant.give) // --> everything
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doind like this.
With that bit inside your json file:

```
"cant": [{"give": "everything", "cause": "its private"}]
```

Use [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) to get the entries inside the "cant" object:

```
var url = 'data.json';
$.getJSON(url, function(json) {
   for (var [key, value] of Object.entries(json.cant[0])) {
       console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
   }
        
});
```